# Flickr streaming python getcomment()

Tags: python, api, streaming, flickr

In the python library flickr for flickr streaming, the method getcomment() dosn't return comments. The following is the methods

```
def getComments(self):
    """"
    get list of comments for photo
    returns a list of comment objects
    comment text is in return [item].text
    """
    method = "flickr.photos.comments.getList"
    try:
        data = _doget(method,  photo_id=self.id)
    except FlickrError: # ???? what errors might there be????
        return None
    return data.rsp.comments
```

the output is

```
<flickr.Bag instance at 0x03F9D378>
8532177364
<flickr.Bag instance at 0x03459828>
8528705440
<flickr.Bag instance at 0x0359B620>
8524405870
<flickr.Bag instance at 0x02D5E1C0>
8521650007
<flickr.Bag instance at 0x02C4CE90>
8519752817
<flickr.Bag instance at 0x02C4CBC0>
```

Comment: what is the output of `dir(data.rsp.comments)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested)

```
comments = photo.getComments()  # Replace photo with name of your object
for comment in comments : 
    print comment.text
```